# Points to line in a river network

Tags: qgis, network, points-to-line

I'm trying to build a network from these points. I've tried points-to-path but it's not giving me the desired output. The problem is that the Node ID that comes from the shapefile is not actually in order, I do have the ID of the next node (NodeDown) and to which reach does each point belongs (toAGReach). Any insight would be great!  I also have the starting and ending point of each reach in another layer if it's worth something.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a data snippet.

Comment: Hi! In the end, I managed to write a short script for my particular case. I could share it here...